# How to remove extra spaces in a string?

Tags: python, django, string

When I get data using API, there are some values that have extra spaces.

For example: `Z Miramar      Wellington  Nz`

How to make this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Z Miramar      Wellington  Nz'
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)
'Z Miramar Wellington Nz'
```

Or [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) followed by a [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> ' '.join(s.split())
'Z Miramar Wellington Nz'
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string then join it again. Something like

```
strText = ' '.join(strText.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

# Using a regular expression, replace any sequence of spaces with a single space
txt = re.sub(' +',' ', txt)
```